# Make this Horizontal Slider Move Vertically instead? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I have an example of a slider I found on codePen here:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tuesta/pen/QoMqBY)

Looking at the Javascript, it's a horizontal slider using **Element.scrollWidth** and **HTMLElement.offsetWidth**, if I want to make the slider move vertically, is it as simple as using scrollHeight instead of scrollWidth and offsetHeight instead of offsetWidth or is there more to it?

Forgive me as I'm newish to Javascript. I'm just looking at how to approach this, what should I be looking at?

```js
const gap = 16;

const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel"),
  content = document.getElementById("content"),
  next = document.getElementById("next"),
  prev = document.getElementById("prev");

next.addEventListener("click", e => {
  carousel.scrollBy(width + gap, 0);
  if (carousel.scrollWidth !== 0) {
    prev.style.display = "flex";
  }
  if (content.scrollWidth - width - gap <= carousel.scrollLeft + width) {
    next.style.display = "none";
  }
});
prev.addEventListener("click", e => {
  carousel.scrollBy(-(width + gap), 0);
  if (carousel.scrollLeft - width - gap <= 0) {
    prev.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (!content.scrollWidth - width - gap <= carousel.scrollLeft + width) {
    next.style.display = "flex";
  }
});

let width = carousel.offsetWidth;
window.addEventListener("resize", e => (width = carousel.offsetWidth));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 964px;
  position: relative;
}

#carousel {
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

#carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

#prev,
#next {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

#prev {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

#next {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="carousel">
        <div id="content">
          <img
            class="item"
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0OynDYRoCaQWJIUyiOrUVeoub0mLNrDUcUZrJXF2WHQD77o-F_g2EnqZqVevO954WzD7mC5qTg=w512-h512-l90-rj"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/e2WxnnYi-F9oN4e0HdLosbq8nlxezfIlxAze2Ba0zE2JR8Es7j-4tNtXc9atwL51FHpaTMtDgmc=w544-h544-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/u6ldIRFJNC856cVGIRsj8It7kz8_0WSTsbdJEOdwjkzZg0lLnn2fFFdhdkCf85HG9O0s2Ak72g=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nlaN4QEwrQivvVocTsTmksMAaLdiOYRI6fqWgEvr8HeszJdwyOLWSMtVZQkFP_jIO47g-sbZ=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ivQK-VEDrumpUKopbgrZKKIP70_i0B0r1LLa7PM1ugqtWJcGDRt8yxndLAVKZn3k5djl6_SS2w=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mH0AFUazs5cUFTMGmXW-yCIhqSgJHbYqt08OjMgON0-x_Q5nsxhOzVwMHyZJ1e3dziP_ja7_=w544-h544-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/H3yFco2fMxBxlQ7wZ7-_OUA8zO8hmqTU9Fik9_lwA6L5pCP_JcCI0OR2XmdAUPzZS_XsayPDnw=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/URcwKIhfH3rPoeSfAKfsuKTwZzyNUv_f9TiLL3Nddscv-cufGX3kh6G8FzkJHzvgWrxKMu_Y36A=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/BkARURW3Om0LVqlubLu1ziGrfKJrkYpSLEQflgH29lmTooSvXQjsHaWnwH1srAPlIMyJKjWqFIU=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JMSMnpSyPX1ZTgodYRg5y98ZeZ5AUMBKf2TMRXD88_i6Qkj6-CwfkqmE0X4THMIPVydnYBNVUg=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            class="item"
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0OynDYRoCaQWJIUyiOrUVeoub0mLNrDUcUZrJXF2WHQD77o-F_g2EnqZqVevO954WzD7mC5qTg=w512-h512-l90-rj"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/e2WxnnYi-F9oN4e0HdLosbq8nlxezfIlxAze2Ba0zE2JR8Es7j-4tNtXc9atwL51FHpaTMtDgmc=w544-h544-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/u6ldIRFJNC856cVGIRsj8It7kz8_0WSTsbdJEOdwjkzZg0lLnn2fFFdhdkCf85HG9O0s2Ak72g=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nlaN4QEwrQivvVocTsTmksMAaLdiOYRI6fqWgEvr8HeszJdwyOLWSMtVZQkFP_jIO47g-sbZ=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ivQK-VEDrumpUKopbgrZKKIP70_i0B0r1LLa7PM1ugqtWJcGDRt8yxndLAVKZn3k5djl6_SS2w=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mH0AFUazs5cUFTMGmXW-yCIhqSgJHbYqt08OjMgON0-x_Q5nsxhOzVwMHyZJ1e3dziP_ja7_=w544-h544-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/H3yFco2fMxBxlQ7wZ7-_OUA8zO8hmqTU9Fik9_lwA6L5pCP_JcCI0OR2XmdAUPzZS_XsayPDnw=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/URcwKIhfH3rPoeSfAKfsuKTwZzyNUv_f9TiLL3Nddscv-cufGX3kh6G8FzkJHzvgWrxKMu_Y36A=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/BkARURW3Om0LVqlubLu1ziGrfKJrkYpSLEQflgH29lmTooSvXQjsHaWnwH1srAPlIMyJKjWqFIU=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
          <img
            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JMSMnpSyPX1ZTgodYRg5y98ZeZ5AUMBKf2TMRXD88_i6Qkj6-CwfkqmE0X4THMIPVydnYBNVUg=w512-h512-l90-rj"
            class="item"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="prev">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" />
          <path d="M15.61 7.41L14.2 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L11.03 12l4.58-4.59z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      <button id="next">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" />
          <path d="M10.02 6L8.61 7.41 13.19 12l-4.58 4.59L10.02 18l6-6-6-6z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

I've tried editing the JS to this:

```
  const gap = 16;

const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel"),
  content = document.getElementById("content"),
  next = document.getElementById("next"),
  prev = document.getElementById("prev");

next.addEventListener("click", e => {
  carousel.scrollBy(0, height + gap);
  if (carousel.scrollHeight !== 0) {
    prev.style.display = "flex";
  }
  if (content.scrollHeight - height - gap <= carousel.scrollTop + height) {
    next.style.display = "none";
  }
});
prev.addEventListener("click", e => {
  carousel.scrollBy(-0,(height + gap));
  if (carousel.scrollTop - height - gap <= 0) {
    prev.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (!content.scrollHeight - height - gap <= carousel.scrollTop + height) {
    next.style.display = "flex";
  }
});

let height = carousel.offsetHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize", e => (height = carousel.offsetHeight));
```

But this doesn't appear to change anything other than breaking the slider.

Comment: *"...or is there more to it?"* There is more to it.

Comment: Have u made it?))